# Regex to return integers in square brackets in a string

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

So I'm finding difficulty in applying regex. Need to create a function which will return a list of integers enclosed in brackets in the string. There can be whitespace between the number and brackets but no other character.

So basically calling the function:

`integers_in_brackets("  afd [asd] [12 ] [a34]  [ -43 ]tt [+12]xxx")`

Should give:

`[12, -43, 12]`

Also, there is no '+' sign in the integers with '+' in the list.

I have already tried this but to no good:

`re.findall(r'[-]?\d+', "  afd [asd] [12 ] [a34]  [ -43 ]tt [+12]xxx")`

This one returns:

`['12', '34', '-43', '12']`

Comment: Your current regex doesn't appear to *attempt* what you describe - it doesn't care about square brackets, for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:  https://repl.it/repls/SizzlingTornUtility

It uses this regex `\[\s*([-+]?\d+)\s*\]`

```
import re
def integers_in_brackets(string):
  answers = [int(a) for a in re.findall(r'\[\s*([-+]?\d+)\s*\]', string)]

  return answers
print(integers_in_brackets("  afd [asd] [12 ] [a34]  [ -43 ]tt [+12]xxx"))
```

returns

`[12, -43, 12]`

Comment: Fun fact: `-` at the start of a a set `[...]` does not need to be escaped (since it can't indicate a range of characters): `[-+]` works just as fine as `[\-+]`.

Comment: You should use `[-+]?` instead of `[-+]*`: the latter allows for e.g. '+-+-+-23'.

Answer (score 0):

Might be overkill, but it works:

```
text = "  afd [asd] [12 ] [a34]  [ -43 ]tt [+12]xxx"
[''.join(re.findall(r'[-]?\d+', _)) for _ in re.findall(r'\[\s?[+]?[-]?\d+\s?\]', text)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here with a good regex and using [`map`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) to convert the items of the list to integers.

```
import re

txt = "  afd [asd] [12 ] [a34]  [ -43 ]tt [+12]xxx"
rgx = "\[\s*\+?(-?\d+)\s*\]"
res = list(map(int, re.findall(rgx, txt)))
print(res)
```

Gives:

```
[12, -43, 12]
```

Answer (score 0):

The following appears to do what you want:

```
>>> text = "  afd [asd] [12 ] [a34]  [ -43 ]tt [+12]xxx"
>>> pattern = r'\[\s*([-+]?\d+)\s*\]'
>>> [int(x) for x in re.findall(pattern, text)]
[12, -43, 12]
```